# From where does static friction transfer energy, in case of a car?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, friction

Let’s take the scenario of a truck which has a block kept on it and it starts to go around in a circular path. It stops later after one circle, at it's initial position. If we consider the journey of a circular path, work is done by static friction, which means there is a transfer of energy, where does static friction get this energy from to transfer, as we know that static friction does not have 'stored' up energy like any other conservative force.

Answer (score 1):

> Let’s take the scenario of a truck which has a block kept on it and it starts to go around in a circular path. … where does static friction get this energy from to transfer

It gets the energy from the truck. The truck, in turn, gets it from the chemical energy in its fuel.